# "File does not exist" error when running ensembl-vep with docker

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

I installed ensembl-vep as instructed in the documentation:

```
cd $HOME/vep_data
curl -O https://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-110/variation/vep/homo_sapiens_vep_110_GRCh38.tar.gz
tar xzf homo_sapiens_vep_110_GRCh38.tar.gz
```

When I tied running the program as follows, the following error message was printed, even though the file does exist:

```
$ sudo docker run -v $HOME/vep_data:/data ensemblorg/ensembl-vep   vep --cache --offline --format vcf --vcf --force_overwrite     
  --input_file input/1000123_23191_0_0.g.vcf       --output_file output/my_output.vcf
-------------------- EXCEPTION --------------------
MSG: ERROR: File "input/1000123_23191_0_0.g.vcf" does not exist

STACK Bio::EnsEMBL::VEP::Parser::file /opt/vep/src/ensembl-vep/modules/Bio/EnsEMBL/VEP/Parser.pm:237
STACK Bio::EnsEMBL::VEP::Parser::new /opt/vep/src/ensembl-vep/modules/Bio/EnsEMBL/VEP/Parser.pm:131
STACK Bio::EnsEMBL::VEP::Runner::get_Parser /opt/vep/src/ensembl-vep/modules/Bio/EnsEMBL/VEP/Runner.pm:802
STACK Bio::EnsEMBL::VEP::Runner::get_InputBuffer /opt/vep/src/ensembl-vep/modules/Bio/EnsEMBL/VEP/Runner.pm:829
STACK Bio::EnsEMBL::VEP::Runner::init /opt/vep/src/ensembl-vep/modules/Bio/EnsEMBL/VEP/Runner.pm:136
STACK Bio::EnsEMBL::VEP::Runner::run /opt/vep/src/ensembl-vep/modules/Bio/EnsEMBL/VEP/Runner.pm:200
STACK toplevel /opt/vep/src/ensembl-vep/vep:46
Date (localtime)    = Wed Aug  2 15:41:03 2023
Ensembl API version = 110
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: And does `input/1000123_23191_0_0.g.vcf` exist? Is it perhaps in another directory?

Comment: Yes:  
`$ ls input/1000123_23191_0_0.g.vcf` prints

`input/1000123_23191_0_0.g.vcf` when outside of the container.

Answer (score 1):

In your docker container you have a completely different overlay filesystem, and therefor `input/1000123_23191_0_0.g.vcf` just does not exist there. You need to make every directory or drive available within your container first using `volumes`(`-v`) as you did with the downloaded dataset:   `-v $HOME/vep_data:/data`

An option would be to add `-v $(pwd)/input:/input` to have everything available inside your container.

It's completely fine if you have several `-v` parameters in you `docker run` command, just make sure they are placed between `run` and the docker-image used

Edit:
In this specific case the program assumes that you put everything into $HOME/vep_data. As taken from the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/Ensembl/ensembl-vep/blob/release/110/docker/Dockerfile) you can see that the working directory in the container is `/data`. In the example you are trying to reproduce, its assumed, that there is e.g. a /data/input directory which contains the file to be processed. So you ultimately have to put your files under `$HOME/vep_data/input` so that the relative paths used in the example are working. Alternative is to use absolute paths and use additional volumes as described above:

`-v /path/to/input:/input .... --input_file /input/myfile.vcf`

I personally prefer absolute paths when working with these containers, as I don't want to rely on some structure that *might* be expected (and change over time with newer versions)

Comment: Thanks.  
I tried applying your suggestion to add another `-v` parameter as follows, yet got the same error again:  
`$ docker run -v $(pwd)/input:/input -v /home/dnanexus:/data ensemblorg/ensembl-vep   vep --cache --offline --format vcf --vcf --
force_overwrite --everything      --input_file input/1000123_23191_0_0.g.vcf       --output_file output/my_output.vcf`  

`MSG: ERROR: Cache directory /opt/vep/.vep/homo_sapiens not found
...`

Comment: Hi. I edited my answer accordingly. There are two errors in your cmd: 1) it should be `-v /home/dnanexus/vep_data:/data`, 2) if you use a second volume you should use absolute paths for the `--input_file /input/1000123_23191_0_0.g.vcf`. But if you want to stick to relative paths check the edits. You probably placed the input file in the wrong directory earlier.

Comment: I used `sudo docker run -v $(pwd)/input:/input -v /home/dnanexus/vep_data:/data   vep --cache --offline --format vcf --vcf --force_o
verwrite --everything      --input_file /home/dnanexus/input/1000123_23191_0_0.g.vcf       --output_file output/my_output.vcf`  which resulted in `Unable to find image 'vep:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for vep, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.`

Comment: That's a completely different error message coming from a step before even starting the `vep` command. Seems like you forgot the image name `ensemblorg/ensembl-vep` in your command.

Comment: I gave up using Docker this time (:

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but I know that feel. Hope you have more luck next time with docker!